# how can i install heroku in my kali linux operating system?

Tags: heroku, kali-linux

I cant install heroku in my kali linux operating system. how can i resolve this issue?

isn't it not possible to run heroku in kali linux?

when I have try to install, it show snap command not found.

Answer (score 3):

[Heroku no longer supports Snap installs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#install-with-an-installer):

> Snap installs are no longer supported. Please use another install method below.

Since [Kali is derived from Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux), you should be able to use [the Debian / Ubuntu method](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#install-with-ubuntu-debian-apt-get) (which doesn't auto-update) or the [standalone tarball method](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#standalone-installation-with-a-tarball) (which does). You can also use [the NPM / Yarn package](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#install-with-npm) if you prefer, though Heroku recommends against it.

All of these options require some amount of trust in Heroku. The first two pull a script down from the Internet and pipe it into `sh`, which always makes me a bit uneasy. I suspect they both request elevated privileges during the install process. Instead of piping the file directly in to `sh` as Heroku recommends, I suggest you download it and at least give it a quick read through the first time.

In any case, here is the command that Heroku recommends to install the standalone version:

```
curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```